# Angular @nebular/theme version 3.6.1 NbAccordionModule missing?

Tags: angular, nebular

I'm a bit new in Nebular theming so when I install @nebular/theme 3.6.1 version, NbAccordionModule module is missing. I wonder how can I use the accordion component ?

I checked the link https://akveo.github.io/nebular/3.6.1/docs/components/accordion/overview#nbaccordioncomponent and there should have NbAccordionModule module.

If anyone has already facing or solving the same issue, I would appreciate your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Import your NbAccordionModule in @NgModule. and then use for component accordion.

imports: [
NbAccordionModule
]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the guideline before Answer a question here.